# Hibernate ConstraintViolationException on SELECT query

Tags: hibernate, hql, unique-constraint, transactional

I have a Persistent Class with multi-field unique constraint on it. But defined unique constraint is not sufficient for me because on one those field non-equal but similar values are unique too.

I implement a `checkUniqueConstraint` method.
In add and update  methods of DAO class, I call `checkUniqueConstraint` before adding or updating persist object.

`checkUniqueConstraint` method just run a SELECT query to find object similar to input and throw a check Exception where find some ones.

```
public class PersistClassDao {    
public void checkUniqueConstraint(PersistClass persistObject) throws DuplicateEntityException {
    /**
    * creating a query string that find persist objects similar to input parameter.
    **/
    try {
        PersistClass result = (PersistClass) query.uniqueResult();
        if(result != null && (persistObject.getId() == null  || persistObject.getId() != result.getId())){
            throw new DuplicateEntityException(exceptionMessage, "");
        } 
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
        throw new DuplicateEntityException(exceptionMessage);
    }
}

public long add(/* field of new persistObject*/) throws DuplicateEntityException {
    //creates a transisent instance of persistObject
    PersistClass newObject = getPersistClass(/* field of new persistObject*/);
    checkUniqueConstraint(newObject);
    try {
        getCurrentSession().save(newObject);
        getCurrentSession().flush();
        return newObject.getId();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        throw new DuplicateEntityException();
    }
}
```

I have a transactionl service mehod for add and another for update.

When I run my test that

- First add 2 persistObjects (through service method).
- Then update one (through service method) them so that be similar to the other
- I expect that DuplicatException be thrown

But really a org.hibernate.exception. ConstraintViolationException  thrown through checkUniqueConstraint!!

Why?

Comment: Show us the code causing the exception, and the exception stack trace. You say you **update** an object through the service method, but the service method **adds** a new object.

Comment: It is difficult to say what the issue is, but from my perspective you are trying to achieve something not desirable. I'd really recommend you think through your DB model and try to get your constraint into the DB instead of solving it in Java.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right and this is an _API_ _defect_ but really our service method updates an existing persist object (by getting persist object id as input param)

Answer (score 4):

The problem must be in **FlushMode**. Hibernate by default flushes entities before executing queries, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html#AUTO.

You must have partially initialized new entities, associated them with the session-bounded ones and now try to do the query. Hibernate session executes flush just before the query and fails with ConstraintViolationException, which is OK.

Solution:

1. change *FlushMode* to *COMMIT* in cfg file for the entire application,
2. modify just a single session by *session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT)* or
3. you can narrow the impact of the change down to the single Query by calling *query.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT)*.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will only flush before `select` if there is any `insert / update` operation before the `select`. By default, Hibernate does not immediately commit changes to the DB when `save` or `update` is called. This is to take advantage of JDBC batching to improve performance. Hibernate will only flush changes to the db when session is **closed**, **transaction is committed** or a **select** is issued to the DB. This flush before `select` is necessary because without the prior changes being flushed to the DB, the query result might not be correct.

So your insert/update is actually a object creation/updation being called before the find method, and is only flushed down to the DB prior to the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the getters or setters inside your `PersistClass` are not plain get/set logic.
If your getter doesn't return the same instance that Hibernate passed to the setter, Hibernate will flush the "dirty" entity upon transaction completion.

Can you paste your `PersistClass` code, and maybe the Hibernate logs to validate that?

Comment: Yes. I had a pair of non-plain getter setter methods but those are correspond to a transient field.