# Working with Hibernate ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I'm struggling on a little problem here. Basically we have a table where a column isn't a PK but needs to be unique, so we added a unicity constraint on it. Now in our service layer we wish to catch the Exception generated when someone creates a record that breaks that unicity constraint, and return the already existing record instead of creating a new one.

Basically, the code looks like this :

```
    ObjectDto object = null;
    try {
        object = convertToDto(objectDao.create(convertToModel(pObject)));
    }
    catch (PersistenceException e) {
        object= getByLabel(pObject.getLabel());
    }
    return object;
```

This... works and at the same time doesn't. We correctly catch the exception and return the object retrieved by the getByLabel() method, but JUnit still shows an error and thus our unit tests don't pass :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Is there another way to treat those usecases ?

EDIT :

```
ObjectDto object = new ObjectDto();
object .setLabel("XXX");
object = objectService.create(object);

ObjectDto object2 = new ObjectDto();
object2.setLabel("XXX");
object2 = objectService.create(object2);
```

Comment: Please share your test code as well

Comment: I had a similiar bug and was reported, says something like "could not commit" but my commit was fine, check your string error message and do nothing, is an option

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your test method with this:

```
@Test(expected=PersistenceException.class)
```

so jUnit will know that an exception will be thrown.

Comment: It indeed solves the issue, but why does it even go all the way up to the test layer given I catch it in the service layer ?

Comment: It shouldn't in fact. Are you sure that your test code isn't doing anything else that can throw that exception? Can you post it?

Comment: I would argue that this doesn't solve your issue. It will make your test green, but you don't expect an Exception at this point but an object

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind right now is that the exception may be thrown from getByLabel(pObject.getLabel()) instead. This would explain why the exception is propagating up to the test method. Can you try insert it into a try-catch to see if that's the case?

Comment: Indeed, you are right. It throws : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: Code :   
`CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object.class);
Root<Object> rootEntry = criteriaQuery.from(Object.class);
criteriaQuery.select(rootEntry);

Predicate predicateLibelle = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEntry.get("label"), pLabel);
criteriaQuery.where(predicateLibelle);
TypedQuery<Object> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Object> listResults = allQuery.getResultList();
if (!listResults.isEmpty()) {
 return listResults.get(0);
}
return null;`

Comment: Which kind of flushMode are you using? Try setting it at commit. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090386/hibernate-constraintviolationexception-on-select-query

Comment: FlushMode should be auto, i'll try to take a look at setting it at commit and hit back at you. Thanks a lot for your help mate !

Comment: It's indeed auto. Haven't found a way yet to change it to COMMIT, that being said I just realise everytime I call the create method of our generic dao, we manually flush and refresh the object before it's returned, to get the generated id's etc. Will this be a problem ? 
`@Override

 public E create(final E pModel) {

  entityManager.persist(pModel);

  entityManager.flush();

  entityManager.refresh(pModel);

  return pModel;

 }`

Comment: Well, manually changing it before the queries to COMMIT leads to a javax.persistence.RollbackException : Transaction marked as rollbackOnly.

Comment: Yeah I think that's a problem. More important, though I think the general approach you are using it's too messy. If I was in you, I'd probably do the select first. If the object is returned then you give it back, else you insert into the db. That would be much more clean and easy in my opinion. Is there any particular reason you are taking this approach?

Comment: I found the problem. Our transactionManager is set to be creating transactions on every method of our service layer (`<tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" />`). Which means the whole method is a transaction and thus once it's rollbackOnly it can't make the select, instead of having two independent transactions.

Comment: You should rollback before calling getByLabel as the first operation if the exception is caught. This will solve your problem for sure.